# CSS Positioning-Position relative and absolute Bootstrap

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

So basically I have in my HTML(using bootstrap classes) a page with products that are showcased using the **thumbnail** and **caption** classes. Over the picture of the products there is a ON SELL(rounded red tag). I have given to this red circle element **position absolute** and to the **col-sm-9 position relative**. Problem is that when I resize the browser the ribbon that comes over the thumbnail is not responsive.

I know what this two positioning properties mean and how they work in respect with each other. But it looks that in practice I`m missing on something very essential.

I will paste my html and css over here and if you can give me your opinion I`ll be very glad to learn this the proper way and give you my thanks :)

Here you have the whole code: http://www.bootply.com/8TMS5WgWt2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your CSS for `.sale` change your positioning value of `left: 149px` to `right: -19px`.  This will help it better position as the width changes.  I would also recommend moving your `position: relative` off the `.col-sm-9` and onto `.thumbnail`

Answer (score 1):

In your css, replace left for right

```
top: -19px;
left: 149px;
```

With left, always it calculate from left position.

```
top: -19px;
right: yourpixels;
```

Here is an example with `right: 0px`
http://www.bootply.com/EzRZnhA2EC#